# How do dynamic sites like Facebook/Google Play Music generate content with so few XHR requests?

Tags: ajax, jsonp

I'm just testing out Google Play Music, and noticed that with so much going on on a single page, how come there aren't many XHR requests showing up in the console?

When I create an AJAX site, every single XHR request I perform (usually using jQuery's $.ajax() method) is clearly visible in the console, as expected. But on mainstream sites, even more so with Facebook, there don't seem to be many visible XHR request going on, and they certainly don't seem to be pinging the server every 10 seconds or so to check for new status updates...!

Alternatives I've read about are persistent connections, and dynamically inserting  tags into the page which presumably pulls data from other sources making it available in the current page.

Comment: I don't know those sites but on SO and other sites the solution is to use websockets.

Comment: Pasvid, you've asked seven questions and have accepted ZERO. Voting for and accepting answers is how other members get "paid" around here. Pony-up, dude.

Comment: A good way to get less requests is to collect several requests into one and get several answers in one HTTP response.

Comment: @Diodeus OK man, I've accepted one of them, but if you look at my other questions not many of them have been conclusively answered, and I don't think it would be useful for others to see an accepted answer that doesn't actually answer the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tried those sites but a common solution, used for example on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), is to use [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). They enable an efficient pushing of information from the server to the client without polling.